# Algorithm to get all pixels between color border?

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics

I have a long png file containing many sprites in a row, but their width/height changes by a little bit. However, all sprites have a fixed blue color 1px border around it.

However, after each sprite, the borders are connected to each other by 2px (just border after border that interacts) see this:

[image: img]

But at the bottom of the sprites, it misses one pixel point

Is there an existing algorithm that can get all pixels between a color border like this, ***including the border*** when giving the pixels?

Or any other ideas how to grab all sprites of one file like this and give them a fixed size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your image and transformed it to match your description.

In plain text I went form left to right and identify lines that might indicate a start or end to an image and used a tracker variable to decide which is which.

I approached it like this in Java:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PixelArtSizeFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File imageFile = new File("pixel_boat.png");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);

        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        System.out.format("Size: %dx%d%n", w, h);

        Raster data = image.getData();

        int objectsFound = 0;
        int startObjectWidth = 0;
        int endObjectWidth = 0;
        boolean scanningObject = false;
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {

            boolean verticalLineContainsOnlyTransparentOrBorder = true;
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                int[] pixel = data.getPixel(x, y, new int[4]);
                if (isOther(pixel)) {
                    verticalLineContainsOnlyTransparentOrBorder = false;
                }
            }

            if (verticalLineContainsOnlyTransparentOrBorder) {
                if (scanningObject) {
                    endObjectWidth = x;
                    System.out.format("Object %d: %d-%d (%dpx)%n",
                            objectsFound,
                            startObjectWidth,
                            endObjectWidth,
                            endObjectWidth - startObjectWidth);
                } else {
                    objectsFound++;
                    startObjectWidth = x;
                }
                scanningObject ^= true; //toggle
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isTransparent(int[] pixel) {
        return pixel[3] == 0;
    }

    private static boolean isBorder(int[] pixel) {
        return pixel[0] == 0 && pixel[1] == 187 && pixel[2] == 255 && pixel[3] == 255;
    }

    private static boolean isOther(int[] pixel) {
        return !isTransparent(pixel) && !isBorder(pixel);
    }
}
```

and the result was

```
Size: 171x72
Object 1: 0-27 (27px)
Object 2: 28-56 (28px)
Object 3: 57-85 (28px)
Object 4: 86-113 (27px)
Object 5: 114-142 (28px)
Object 6: 143-170 (27px)
```

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) If you find you want your post to include more information, edit it instead of commenting. (If you have a comment that you don't want to be proper contents, just comment…)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if any algorithm or function already exists for this but what you can do is : 
while the boats are all the same and you wanna get all the pixels between two blue pixels so you can use something like this :

```
 for all i in vertical pixels 
    for all j in horizontal pixels 
        if pixel(i,j) == blue then 
           j = j+ 1 
            while pixel(i,j) != blue then 
              you save this pixel in an array for example 
              j = j+1
            end while 
         end if 
     end for 
 end for
```

This is just an idea and for sure not the most optimal but you can you use it and perform it to make it better ;)